# fadein effect with scriptaculous

Tags: prototypejs, scriptaculous

I want to fade effect of the div, the following script doesn't work. What can be the problem? Thanks a lot.

```
function fadeIn(){

    $('test').invoke("fade", {
        from: 0, 
        to: 1,
        afterFinish: function() {

             $('test').setStyle({
                 display: 'block'               
             });           
        }
    });
}

<div class='top'>
    <div id="test" style="display:none">
         Fade in test
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" onClick="fadeIn(); ">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`invoke`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/) is a method of `Enumerable`, and [`$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/) returns an `Element`, not an `Enumerable`.

Since `$` is effectively an alias for `getElementById`, there is no need for it to return an array of elements (you can only have one element with any given `id`, so only one element will ever be returned).

You can just call `fade` directly on the element:

```js
$('test').fade({
    from: 0, 
    to: 1,
    afterFinish: function() {
        $('test').setStyle({
            display: 'block'               
        });           
    }
});
```